# An Adobe Flash-based RTSP Player with particular video and audio codecs

Tags: video, streaming, flash

I'm researching RTSP/RTP streaming players.

The minimum specification of the player should be as below:

1. The player must support H.264 video codec (baseline profile)
2. The player must support PCM G.711 u-low, G.726, AAC-LC audio codec
3. The player must support high definition resolution at least FullHD (1920x1080)

I've already tested [axis-locomote](https://github.com/AxisCommunications/locomote-video-player). It doesn't work with our server.
(It's an RTSP server we developed tested many times with many RTSP clients and worked fine.)

[FStreamer](http://www.fstreamer.com) works great but several conditions are not met. (FStreamer doesn't support FullHD res and support audio codecs only AAC, MP3.)

It would be on web application over the internet.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As this question was migrated here from webapps: is it safe to assume you're looking for a web-app – or should it be installed locally? In the latter case: what OS must be supported? Please [edit] your question and include this. Thanks!